# Stitching TIF tiles into large image

Tags: linux, imagemagick, tiff, photo-stitching

I have a list of 25 TIF images (map tiles), each around 400 MiB in size (each small rectangle here):

[image]

I need to stitch them into one single huge TIF. Is there a command under Linux that can do this? I can provide absolute X/Y coordinates for every tile.

I tried it with the `montage` command (part of Imagemagick), but it seems to support only tilesets where each row / column has the same number of tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a command under Linux that can do this?

I personally am not aware of a single command to do what you want.

> I tried it with the montage command (part of Imagemagick), but it seems to support only tilesets where each row / column has the same number of tiles.

I don't know if this would be a solution for you, but you could (theoretically) generate the missing images beforehand, then simply include them in the `montage` command.

For your example image, assuming you had e.g. `slice_1_1.tif` to `slice_1_6.tif` for the first row, `slice_2_1.tif` to `slice_2_6.tif` for the second row, etc., [you could generate "blank" images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504522/create-blank-image-in-imagemagick) with something like the following:

```
magick -size 120x85 canvas:white slice_1_1.tif
magick -size 70x85 canvas:white slice_1_6.tif
magick -size 70x85 canvas:white slice_2_6.tif
magick -size 120x85 canvas:white slice_5_5.tif
magick -size 70x85 canvas:white slice_5_6.tif
```

You would, of course, need to use the correct sizes for your actual images. You could then run `montage` as normal:

```
magick montage *.tif -tile 6x5 -geometry +0+0 example.tif
```

which would give you something like:

[image: Example TIF]

Assuming there weren't any other considerations, I think the toughest part here would (potentially) be automating the "missing" image generation (assuming you needed to do that for some reason).

---

*ImageMagick References*

- [Solid Color Canvases](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#solid)
- [Montage](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/)

Comment: Thanks! You're right, this should work.